# Returning from an anonymous function won't work, even though it's not async

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, return, anonymous-function

I have the following function:

```
function filterDesiredURLs(tweet) {
    tweet.entities.urls.forEach((url) => {
        desiredURLs.forEach((regexPattern) => {
            if (regexPattern.test(url['expanded_url'])) {
                console.log('hello, im returning');
                return true;
            }
        })
    })
}
```

And I'm calling it like this:

```
console.log(filterDesiredURLs(tweet));
```

Where tweet is a defined object. I can see that the function is indeed returning because I see the output `hello, im returning` in the console, but the `console.log(filterDesiredURLs(tweet));`prints `undefined`. I would expect this for anonymous functions passed as callbacks for async operations, but this is not async, so the return should work. What's happening?

Comment: You're returning from the inner function, not the outer function. `Array#forEach` ignores the return value of its callback.

Comment: It looks like your code should be using [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead of two `forEach` loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` doesn't operate across function boundaries.  It only returns from the *innermost* function.  To do what you want you probably want [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) or [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) coupled with [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
function filterDesiredURLs(tweet) {
  // First, you were missing a return in the outer function
  // Without a return here, *this* function will return `undefined`
  return tweet.entities.urls.filter(url => {
    // We are using `filter` to reduce the URL list to only
    // URLs that pass our test - this inner function needs to return
    // a boolean (true to include the URL, false to exclude it)
    return desiredURLs.some(regexPattern => {
      // Finally, we use `some` to see if any of the regex patterns match
      // This method returns a boolean value. If the function passed to it ever 
      // returns true, it terminates the loop and returns true
      // Otherwise, it iterates over the entire array and returns false.
      return regexPattern.test(url['expanded_url']);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Note, that depending on your regular expression's complexity vs. the *number* of them it *may* make more sense to combine all of your regular expressions by "or-ing" them together and testing with the combined regex once.  But that's likely a micro-optimization.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `return` like that, you're returning from the closest function (in this case, the anonymous function passed as argument to your inner `forEach`).

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return):

> The return statement ends function execution and specifies a value to
>   be returned to the function caller.

To accomplish your goal, you may try this:

```
function filterDesiredURLs(tweet) {
    let found = false;
    tweet.entities.urls.forEach((url) => {
        desiredURLs.forEach((regexPattern) => {
            if (regexPattern.test(url['expanded_url'])) {
                console.log('hello, im returning');
                found = true;
                /* don't need return because forEach does not expects a function that returns something; and you can't break forEach */
            }
        })
    })
    return found;
}
```

Comment: `return;` won't break the `forEach`, it will just exit that single iteration. Think of it like a `continue;` statement in a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript `forEach` method returns `undefined`.

`forEach` is an operation which retains the array as immutable and returns a new array. In your code, the `forEach` method is called and it doesn't return anything, hence `undefined`.